# Cannot resolve string supplied to vararg parameter in extension function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="my_string">Showing your number: %1$s</string>
```

**ActivityExt.kt**

```
fun Activity.showToast(textResId: Int, vararg formatArgs: String) {
    val text = getString(textResId, formatArgs)
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
val number = 11
showToast(R.string.my_string, number.toString())
```

Toast with following text is showing:

```
Showing your number: [Ljava.lang.String;@2cfa3b]
```

Why this happens?

Answer (score 24):

Use the [spread](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) operator:

```
fun Activity.showToast(textResId: Int, vararg formatArgs: String) {
    val text = getString(textResId, *formatArgs)
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Currently, you're passing an array as the format argument. By using the spread operator you pass the contents of the array as the format argument.

Answer (score 17):

You should use the [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) to pass in the varargs to the `getString` function:

```
val text = getString(textResId, *formatArgs)
```

This is because the type of `formatArgs` inside the `showToast` function is `Array<String>` (there's no `vararg` type or anything like that), and if you pass that in without the `*`, you'll only pass a single parameter, which will be the array instead of its contents.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the other one yet, I was on mobile. I'll leave this up just in case the explanation about the type helps anyone.